# Java: Error says undeclared variable, but I think I have declared it already?

Tags: java

I'm trying to let a user set a new number via dialogbox. The error says:  Undeclared variable: getMembers. What am I doing wrong? Btw, I have a superclass, subclass and a testclass (Main) file. This code is in the testclass (main file), and the method Members is in the Subclass file.

code in main file:

```
int members;
String sR4=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How many members?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);   
           amount=Integer.parseInt(sR4); 
           IdeellForening if2=new IdeellForening(namn, adress, amount); 
           if2.setMembers (members);                 
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,if2.getMembers);
```

Code in subclass IdeellForening:

```
public class IdeellForening extends Forening                                
{
 
    private int members;                                             
    private String namn;         
    private String adress;

    
    public IdeellForening(String namn, String adress, int members)
    {
        
        super(namn, adress);                                                 
        this.members=members;                                    
    }
    public IdeellForening(String namn, int members)            
    {
    this.namn=namn;
    this.registreringsar=0;
    this.members=members;
    }
    
    public void setMembers(int members)
    {
         
        this.members=members;
        
    }
    public int getMembers()
    {
        
        return members;
        
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        
        return "Antalet medlemmar är:  " + members + " och adress" + adress + super.toString();
        
    }
}
```

I've obviously declared the variable/method in the subclass so why does it say I havent?
How can I let the user change input via get set methods and dialogboxes then?

Thankful for any help

Comment: `getMembers` is a method, so you should call it the way methods are called - `if2.getMembers()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMembers` is a method, not a variable.

You need to add `()` to call it:

```
if2.getMembers()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Error message "**The error says: Undeclared variable: getMembers.**" show due to this line :
`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,if2.getMembers);`

You have used **if2.getMembers** in the method parameter of showMessageDialog() *getMembers* is not a variable while in actual its a *getter* method. change it with the method **if2.getMembers()** instead as
`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,if2.getMembers());`